# Raw html method in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to apply different styles for different lines of a paragraph which has binded dynamically in typescript

I tried to split my string variable by line but I am having tags in my variable.Can anyone provide raw html method in typescipt not in html

Can anyone provide me solution in typescript

kindly find below paragraph which is styled differently for different lines which i need as output

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide example of your issue? It is not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: Can you provide a desired output?

Comment: If you want the fade effect where each line gets less visible, that can be done with a gradient to transparent image over your text using CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by adding a fade to transparent gradient over your text paragraf.

[Example on codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/POJQPg)

HTML

```
<div class="box">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
     eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore 
     magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
     exercitation ullamco. </p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
  width: 320px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box > p {
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left 50%, left bottom, from(rgba(0,0,0,1)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0)));
}
```

Comment: hi its working fine thanks.But It varies depends upon  the paragraph size.I need to show only 2 lines clearly means.What I need to do

Comment: Pace only the text you want to show inside the paragraf